Film where Martians/alien siblings on Earth need skin contact to communicate?
I remember this moment (or a moment similar?) from a film I watched when I was a child; it’s been 30 years.
From memory the Martians were in a room with two other children?

What do you mean by "skin contact"? Touching hands? Hands to face? How did you know they were Martian children? What did they look like (greens skin?, antennae?). Do you remember the language of the film? B/W or color?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Possibly 1984's "Slapstick of Another Kind", starring Jerry lewis and Madeline Kahn, based on Kurt Vonnegut's 1976 novel "Slapstick"?

@StanleyWebb Thank you, this is it!

This is "Slapstick of Another Kind".
The following description has been slightly edited from the Wikipedia article.
Slapstick of Another Kind is a 1984 American comic science fiction film starring Jerry Lewis, Madeline Kahn and Marty Feldman. It was filmed in 1982, and released in March 1984 by both The S. Paul Company/Serendipity Entertainment Releasing Company and International Film Marketing. The film was written and directed by Steven Paul and is based on the novel Slapstick (1976) by Kurt Vonnegut.
Plot
The People's Republic of China is severing relations with all other nations. They have mastered the art of miniaturization, and have shrunk all their people to the height of two inches. The ambassador of China, Ah Fong, announces during a press conference that the key to all knowledge can be found from twins.
Caleb Swain and his wife Letitia are called "the most beautiful of all the beautiful people" by the press. However, when Letitia gives birth to twins who are called "monsters", the family doctor, Dr. Frankenstein, informs the parents that the twins won't live more than a few months. The Swains decide to allow the twins to live their short life in a mansion staffed with servants, including Sylvester.
Fifteen years later, the twins are still alive. They have large heads and appear to be mentally disabled. Their parents, who have not seen them in all those years, receive a visit from the former Chinese ambassador who informs them that their children are geniuses who can solve the world's problems.
Along with the President of the United States, the parents pay the children a visit. They reveal themselves to be well-behaved and intelligent, explaining that they behaved "stupid" around the servants because they were simply emulating them.
A series of tests reveal that there is a telepathic connection between the twins, and their intelligence is only functional when they are together. Furthermore, when their heads are touching they reach a level of intelligence that has never been surpassed.
Fearful of incest, the parents separate the two. They become despondent without each other, and the Chinese ambassador appears again to order them to seek out each other. Once united, a spaceship appears and reveals that they are really aliens who were sent to Earth to solve all of the planet's problems. However, their alien father reveals that Earth cannot handle their intelligence and returns them to their home world.

